# JS ForEach Loops in IE11

Tags: javascript, loops, internet-explorer, foreach, internet-explorer-11

I am having issues getting a JS loop to work over 4 elements on a page in IE11. I want the function `hideImg` to run on mouseover on the element that you hovered over.

Here is my code:

```
elements.forEach( function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('mouseover', hideImg);
});
```

I think I've found that `forEach` loops are not supported in IE, how can I easily convert this to a `for` loop in plain JS?

Kind regards,
Steve

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { elements[i].addEventListener("mouseover", hideImg); }`.

Comment: Array.prototype.forEach is supported since IE9.

Comment: true. but it seems that i also loops through non iterable attributes, for example the unique id....

Answer (score 24):

You can do it like this:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('mouseover', hideImg);
}

function hideImg() {
  console.log("hideImg called")
}
```

```css
.test {
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  border: green solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much this works great in IE. Why do you think my question has been downvoted? I am a beginner to JS.

Comment: It was a simple question and you should have explored it on your on, if you are a beginner, you should first go through basics like conditional statements, loops, functions and Objects. MDN is good source to start with https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: Okay, thanks for the feedback, and thanks again for your help.

Comment: @SteveWalker grab a modern browser if you're going to try examples from the internet. IE11 is one of the older supported browsers around and is missing a number of features you'll find in Edge, Chrome & Firefox.

Comment: @SteveWalker Do mark this as the right answer if it helped you solve your issue. Cheers.

Comment: This doesn't necessarily answer the question. OP was asking about `foreach` alternatives, like the answer specified below. There will be times in which using a for loop is inappropriate.

Answer (score 19):

This code will fix your issue in IE 11.

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(elements).forEach( function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('mouseover', hideImg);
});
```

Answer (score 10):

**Just add this to your code at the top of it**
the code provided is supported in all **Browsers**

```
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Can also use the somewhat more compact:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('mouseover', hideImg);
});
```

Or even more compact:

```
[].forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('mouseover', hideImg);
});
```

Note that some programmers prefer to avoid the latter method because it creates an otherwise unused empty array.