# Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach' IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, internet-explorer

I have below snippet

```
data.forEach(function (row) {
var dataRow = [];

columns.forEach(function (column) {

dataRow.push(row[column].toString());
})
```

which is giving me error `data.forEach(function (row) {`
 .What should be alternate to this? How to resolve it?

Comment: Else you can also use the polyfil 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: @brk this polyfill is for Array#forEach The one the dupe target was talking about is [NodeList#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Polyfill). Also, RAM can you confirm it was indeed this NodeList#forEach that you were trying to use.

Comment: [nodelist#forEach polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Polyfill) - I doubt the OP was talking about NodeList though

Comment: Yes, it sounds more like `data` is not what it should be. I reopen ([save-link-to-prev-dupe-target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534102/js-foreach-loops-in-ie11)). But note that as it stands this question should still be closed, because it lacks some information and debugging steps you should have taken on your side (like what is `data` before you call its non-existent forEach method?)

Comment: You can't loop through forEach when data is an object. It should run on array.
In order to loop through the object, you should try:

    for (var key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log(key + " -> " + data[key]); // Here you will get key and value
        }
    }

Answer (score 12):

For anyone using `document.querySelectorAll('..').forEach()` and having this issue in IE 11 saying "forEach is not a function", I found a hack on reddit which worked nicely:

```
if (typeof NodeList.prototype.forEach !== 'function')  {
    NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
}
```

This works perfectly and is 3 lines of code instead of a polyfill.

@JoeTaras hinted at this in his answer (yes IE *does* have `Array.forEach` since IE9), but I still think my answer adds value and will help other users.

Comment: This was posted at the perfect time!  Many thanks! Don't know why the damage, but this is gold!

Answer (score 2):

`IE11` knows `forEach` statement (is IE compliant from IE 9.0, see [**here**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp)), but if you want you can use instead of `forEach` you can use `for` statement, as follow:

I've edited my answer, add a check on data object if is an array

```
if (data != null && Array.isArray(data)) {
    var dataRow = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var row = data[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < columns.length; i++) {
            var column = columns[i];

            dataRow.push(row[column].toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's assuming the `data` variable holds an indexed object, which is a strong assumption given it doesn't have a *#forEach* method. + `var foo=bar` in for loop...

Comment: @Kaiido: Hi, yes, I'm based on question. But now I edit my question

Comment: Ah no, we know at least that `data` **is not** an Array. Luckily IE11 does support Array#forEach